# Z rotation causing skew Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, graphics-programming, opengl-es2

If I rotate about the X, or Y axis there is no skewing however for a pure 2D game that does not help me.  When I try to rotate about the Z axis however the quad I am rendering for the sprite starts to skew until it disappears at 90 degrees appearing again shortly after a slowly resuming a quad shape.  As far as I can tell I have written the code correctly, it is as I have written it before on 2D projects and it worked there I am either missing something stupid or OpenGL ES 2.0 does something different then what I expect, some excerpts of code follow:

Projection/View:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(ViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.orthoM(ProjectMatrix, 0, -width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 0 , 100);
```

Rotation/Scale/Translation(For in place set to identity first):

```
Matrix.translateM(Translation, 0, x, y, 1.0f);  
Matrix.setRotateM(Rotation, 0, angle += 0.05f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Matrix.scaleM(Scale, 0, 64,64,1.0f);
```

Multiplication of Matrices:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, ProjectMatrix, 0, ViewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, MVPMatrix, 0, Translation,0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, MVPMatrix, 0, Rotation, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, MVPMatrix, 0, Scale, 0);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Though I don't know too much of matrix transformations and stuff, I know you should pay attention to the order of translations/rotations.

Comment: The issue here was Matrix.multiplyMM, and using MVPMatrix as the output put and the input.  In most all other libraries I used/made that would be correct.  However looking closer at the specification for the function the api provided is undefined if any of the inputs or outputs overlap.

Comment: @leonmajere What Matrix library are you using for android on java? Just a curiosity.

Comment: android.opengl.Matrix http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was Matrix.multiplyMM, and using MVPMatrix as the output put and the input. In most all other libraries I used/made that would be correct. However looking closer at the specification for the function the api provided is undefined if any of the inputs or outputs overlap